# конфликт при миграции Code First

Tags: c#, база-данных, миграция, codefirst

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, вылетает ошибка при миграции на добавление связи между таблицами

```
Конфликт инструкции ALTER TABLE с ограничением FOREIGN KEY "FK_dbo.Books_dbo.Authors_AuthorId". Конфликт произошел в базе данных "test2_bd", таблица "dbo.Authors", column 'Id'.
```

Вот два класа

```
public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NameBook { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }

public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

изначально создал таблицы без связей, сейчас при добавлении связи

```
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public Author Author { get; set; }
```

вылетает ошибка. Не могу разобраться в чем причина, я так понимаю ему не нравится поле Id, но делал аналогично с другими таблицами все было ок.

Comment: Может, вы в таблицу с книгами уже какие то данные ввели?

Comment: @tym32167 ну таблица с книгами была уже с данными, только разве это играет роль? к примеру, есть база данных с данными, и вдруг решили добавить еще таблицу со связями, не удалять же данные все

Comment: вы добавляете в таблицу с данными поле `public int AuthorId` которое не может быть пустым. Вопрос - к каким авторам должны будут быть привязаны существующие книги?

Comment: @tym32167 вы имеете ввиду, нужно чтобы были данные в таблице с авторами?

Comment: допустим у вас 2 книги в таблице с книгами. "Война и Мир" и  "Му МУ". Вы добавляете кологку для каждой из книг - ид автора. Как ваша миграция поймет, какого автора к какой книге приписать?

Comment: @tym32167 а если мы создаем базу с нуля, в таблицах нету данных, как в таком случае оно осуществит связь?

Comment: Если без данных, то не надо никакие зпписи ни к каким авторам привязывать, потому столбец id автора создатся нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю добавляя жесткую привязку книги к автору, при миграции уже созданные строки выдают ошибку, что FK не определен. Для связей таблиц используйте `Nullable<int>` или `int?`. И для удобства используйте ключевое слово `virtual` для связанного класса, он будет подтягивать его автоматически из БД.
Пример:

```
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NameBook { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

        public Author()
        {
             Books = new List<Book>();
        }
    }
```

Ну и что почитать:
[Code First](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/2.6.php)
[Один ко многим](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.3.php)